# Costs of Thread.sleep(1) are different depending on busy-loop implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, benchmarking, jmh

Suppose we execute `Thread.sleep(1)` within a loop iterating `n` times (here and below it's Java 11):

```java
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(jvmArgsAppend = {"-Xms1g", "-Xmx1g"})
public class ThreadSleep1Benchmark {
  @Param({"5", "10", "50"})
  long delay;

  @Benchmark
  public int sleep() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < delay; i++) {
      Thread.sleep(1);
    }
    return hashCode();
  }
}
```

This benchmark demonstrates the following results:

```
Benchmark                    (delay)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep        5  avgt   50   6,552 ± 0,071  ms/op
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep       10  avgt   50  13,343 ± 0,227  ms/op
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep       50  avgt   50  68,059 ± 1,441  ms/op
```

Here we see that method `sleep()` takes more than `n` milliseconds while intuitively we would expect it to be `~n` as at each iteration current thread sleeps for 1 ms. This example demonstrates the costs of putting thread asleep and awakening it.

Let's now modify the benchmark:

```java
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(jvmArgsAppend = {"-Xms1g", "-Xmx1g"})
public class ThreadSleep2Benchmark {
  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  volatile boolean flag;

  @Param({"5", "10", "50"})
  long delay;

  @Setup(Level.Invocation)
  public void setUp() {
    flag = true;
    startThread();
  }

  @TearDown(Level.Trial)
  public void tearDown() {
    executor.shutdown();
  }

  @Benchmark
  public int sleep() throws Exception {
    while (flag) {
      Thread.sleep(1);
    }
    return hashCode();
  }

  private void startThread() {
    executor.submit(() -> {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
        flag = false;
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here we run a background thread that waits for `n` milliseconds and puts the flag down while the `sleep()` method iterates over `while(flag)` loop. As soon as the flag is put down after delay of `n` milliseconds we expect `while` loop iterate approximately `n` times.

And again we see costs of `Thread.sleep(1)` but they appear to be almost same for `delay` of 5 and 10 significantly lower for the case when `delay` is 50. Pay attention, that the difference here is not linear: it is ~0,1 ms for 5, ~1,2 ms for 10 and ~13 ms for 50.

```
Benchmark                    (delay)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep        5  avgt   50   6,760 ± 0,070  ms/op
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep       10  avgt   50  12,496 ± 0,050  ms/op
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep       50  avgt   50  54,727 ± 0,599  ms/op
```

On Java 18 results are similar:

```
Benchmark                    (delay)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep        5  avgt   50   6,609 ± 0,105  ms/op
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep       10  avgt   50  13,233 ± 0,148  ms/op
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep       50  avgt   50  66,017 ± 0,714  ms/op

ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep        5  avgt   50   6,740 ± 0,067  ms/op
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep       10  avgt   50  12,400 ± 0,112  ms/op
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep       50  avgt   50  53,836 ± 0,250  ms/op
```

So my question is: whether the effect of costs reduction in `ThreadSleep2Benchmark` is compiler's achievement (loop unrolling etc.) or is it about how I iterate over the loops?

**UPD**

For Linux I've got the following results:

```
Java 11

Linux

Benchmark                    (delay)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep        5  avgt   50   5.597 ± 0.038  ms/op
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep       10  avgt   50  11.263 ± 0.069  ms/op
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep       50  avgt   50  56.079 ± 0.267  ms/op

Benchmark                    (delay)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep        5  avgt   50   5.600 ± 0.032  ms/op
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep       10  avgt   50  10.558 ± 0.052  ms/op
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep       50  avgt   50  50.625 ± 0.049  ms/op

Java 18

Benchmark                    (delay)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep        5  avgt   50   5.581 ± 0.041  ms/op
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep       10  avgt   50  11.069 ± 0.067  ms/op
ThreadSleep1Benchmark.sleep       50  avgt   50  55.719 ± 0.602  ms/op

Benchmark                    (delay)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep        5  avgt   50   5.574 ± 0.035  ms/op
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep       10  avgt   50  10.918 ± 0.035  ms/op
ThreadSleep2Benchmark.sleep       50  avgt   50  50.823 ± 0.055  ms/op
```

Comment: I would guess this has more to do with the granularity of the OS timer combined with thread scheduling by the OS than anything else.

Comment: Is there any real-world problem you're trying to approximate with this?  Putting `Thread.sleep(1)` in a repeat loop with no other work is a terrible way to make a delay function.  If you want to know what real-world implementation details led to these results, you should specify what OS and hardware you're running on.  (And your OS configuration.  e.g. for Linux, [How to check HZ in the terminal?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12480486) to check on scheduler timeslice, or if it's a "tickless" kernel, and also relevant if built with real-time kernel patches to make short sleeps like this more accurate)

Comment: It's been my experience that a sleep duration of fewer than 5 milliseconds is unreliable.

Comment: @PeterCordes this is run on MacOS and Intel Core i7, though I think in this case we shouldn't dive into OS/hardware details. The code is quite simple and high-level, so I would expect it to behave +- in the same way on all platforms.

Comment: That is a highly unreasonable expectation.  A Java `sleep` should give control of that CPU core back to the OS, not use a delay loop to waste CPU time for a millisecond, so OS task scheduling details are extremely relevant, and probably most of the answer to your question.  Timing details of OS sleep services for sleeps shorter than scheduling granularity, and CPU power management to govern wake-up latency, are going to be platform-specific, not something any given JVM can really control for.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for explanation, at home I'll run this on Linux and update the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've updated the question, for Linux the difference is less significant yet still present.

Answer (score 2):

If you want more control on pausing a Java thread, have a look at LockSupport.parkNanos. Under Linux by default, you can get 50 us resolution. For more info and how to tune it, see https://hazelcast.com/blog/locksupport-parknanos-under-the-hood-and-the-curious-case-of-parking/

Comment: Thanks! Which approach of considered (sleep, on spin wait, yield, pard nanos) is preferable to you?

Comment: It depends. It can be a combination and be pulled into a strategy. See the following for an example: https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.agrona/Agrona/0.9.1/org/agrona/concurrent/IdleStrategy.html